# jQuery if / else if statement priorities

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, drop-down-menu, keyboard

I am trying to understand why my code does not work the way I want it to. In the comments I am expalaining what each part means.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    // if hit > arrow key
    if(event.keyCode == 39){

      // if nav's level 1 dropdown list is not displayed, use > arrow in level 0
      if ($('nav li .sub-menu').css('display', 'none')){
        $('nav li.active').next().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


      // else if level 1 dropdown list is displayed, use > arrow in level 1
      }else if ($('nav li.active .sub-menu').css('display', 'block') && $('nav .sub-menu li').hasClass('has-child')){ 


         // open level 2 dropdown list
         $('nav li.active .sub-menu li.has-child').find('.sub-sub-menu').stop().hide(); 
      }
    }        
});
```

The problem is, it does not go into else if statement, no matter if dropdown list is displayed or not, therefore > arrow keeps working in level 0 (nav). If I use if statement instead else if, > arrow works both in level 0 and level 1, and its not what I am looking for.

If anyone knows whats wrong with my code, I would appreciate to hear your answer. Thank you.

Comment: The condition `$('nav li .sub-menu').css('display', 'none')` doesn't do any comparison, it always passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('nav li .sub-menu').css('display', 'none')` sets the display to `none`, it does not check its value. That is why it is not working.

What you want to do is:

```
if($('nav li .sub-menu').css('display') === 'none)
```

The same goes for the `else` statement. You should have something like this instead:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    // if hit > arrow key
    if(event.keyCode == 39){
      var nav = $('nav li .sub-menu');
      var navDisplay = nav.css('display');

      // if nav's level 1 dropdown list is not displayed, use > arrow in level 0
      if (navDisplay === 'none'){
        $('nav li.active').next().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


      // else if level 1 dropdown list is displayed, use > arrow in level 1
      }else if (navDisplay === 'block' && nav.hasClass('has-child')){ 


         // open level 2 dropdown list
         $('nav li.active .sub-menu li.has-child').find('.sub-sub-menu').stop().hide(); 
      }
    }        
});
```

Try to get into the habit of storing the results of your jQuery calls if you know you are going to reuse them, these DOM calls can get pretty expensive.

Comment: Good answer.  You can probably remove `navDisplay === 'block' && ` from the `else` test, because it's unlikely that the display style would be anything but `block` when it's not `none`.

Comment: I do agree @RickHitchcock. Personally I wouldn't even grab the display property but rather check visibility using `:visible`. However when I answer modifying someone's code I try to change as little as possible. I don't want to confuse OP or break his code by making assumptions

Comment: @Pabs123 thank you but if i use this code, then it does not work in level 0 even tho navDisplay is none. do you know why?

Comment: @naomi88 it's pretty hard for me to debug your code without having actual HTML to go along with your explanation. The above answer is correct given the info you've given, perhaps your selectors are incorrect in that if statement? can you check if it's actually going into that case by putting a debugger? that should let you know what's wrong

Comment: @Pabs123 I decided to go with if($('nav li .sub-menu').css('display') === 'none')) because it does work using full DOM somehow. Thank you a lot for your help! :)

Comment: @naomi88 no problem! please accept if it fixed your issues. best of luck with whatever you're building!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here.

You can do:

```
if($('nav li .sub-menu').css('display') === 'none'))
```

**OR**

```
if($('nav li .sub-menu:visible'))
```

**OR**

```
if($('nav li .sub-menu').is(":visible")))
```

The last one is the prettiest and pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the display not checking the state. 
try this to check if your element is hidden or not

```
$('nav li.active .sub-menu').is(":visible")
```